# How many ways are there to arrange the letters in STATISTICAL?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My Work:

This is clearly a permutation so

I used $P(11; 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1) = 831600$ ways

Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is a permutation of multiset . There are three T's, two S's, two A's two I's,one C and one L.

$\dfrac{11!}{3!2!2!2!1!1!}$

Comment: Actually, it is a [permutation of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets) since each letter may only be used as often as it appears in the word.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig: I edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, STATISTICAL is a word of type 1232412456, i.e., $1^22^33^24^25^16^1$, and so the multinomial coefficient $$11\choose {2,3,2,2,1,1}$$ gives the result. Your reasoning is a bit short.